# NeoVim cant find "keymap" (a nil value)

Tags: lua, neovim

Im following "ThePrimeagen" tutorial on setting up NeoVim (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w7i4amO_zaE), but Im stuck at 3:13 where he ":so" (sources) the file.
In my case I get the error:
`E5108: Error executing lua [string ":source (no file)]:2: attempt to index field 'keymap' (a nil value) stack traceback: [string ":source (no file)"]:2: in main chunk`

I dont know much about lua, but what I understand is that it cant find "keymap", thats weird, everything works till now, I placed the `nvim/lua` folder on the right place, init.lua files work, only this remap that doesnt.
Any ideas on a solution?

the remap.lua file:

```lua
vim.g.mapleader = " "
vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>pv", vim.cmd.Ex)
```

Comment: Your post is not enough detailed. Please, post your Lua configuration files if you want some help.

Comment: @Icheylus thats all the code in the lua file

Comment: I had a similar issue, I can :so the file, and requiring it on the init.lua file at the root. I won't work

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wrong syntax.
It should be `vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>pv", ":Ex<CR>")`. `vim.cmd("Ex")` will open up netrw each time you source the file.

Comment: Thank you, I was following ThePrimagen tutorial, he uses what I typed, but yours worked.

Comment: I also came from that tutorial and for those not getting their problem fixed with this solution you need to update nvim to something greater than `7.0.0`.

Comment: I ran into this too. It's the wrong syntax for any neovim version less than 0.7.0. Ubuntu's repo only has version 0.6.X so I decided to build and install from source.

Answer (score 9):

Just install unstable neovim version:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:neovim-ppa/unstable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install neovim
```

Comment: Cant find a unstable version for Windows.

Answer (score 2):

I decided to build from source instead of dealing with the different apt repos.

Here are the steps I followed:

1. Open a terminal on your Ubuntu system.
2. Install the required dependencies for building Neovim by running the following command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install ninja-build gettext libtool libtool-bin autoconf automake cmake g++ pkg-config unzip
   ```
3. Clone the Neovim repository from GitHub by running the following command:

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/neovim/neovim.git
   ```
4. Change to the Neovim directory:

   ```
   cd neovim
   ```
5. Checkout the Neovim 0.9.1 release tag:

   ```
   git checkout v0.9.1
   ```
6. Build and install Neovim using the following commands:

   ```
   make CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo
   sudo make install
   ```

Answer (score 1):

None of the provided answers worked for me even though I was using the appimage
of [version 0.9.1](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/releases/download/v0.9.1/nvim.appimage) from [neovim release page](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/releases) so here is what I had to do:

1. Used `dpkg --list` command to see all the packages related to nvim and vim on my system then purged them:

```bash
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove vim
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove vim.tiny
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove nvim
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove neovim
```

2. Installed it via [appimage as described in their repo](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/Installing-Neovim#install-from-package):

```bash
./nvim.appimage --appimage-extract
./squashfs-root/AppRun --version

# Optional: exposing nvim globally.
sudo mv squashfs-root /
sudo ln -s /squashfs-root/AppRun /usr/bin/nvim
nvim
```

And since I'm using Debian, also followed [their instructions](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/Installing-Neovim#debian) to update paths:

```bash
CUSTOM_NVIM_PATH=/usr/bin/nvim
# Set the above with the correct path, then run the rest of the commands:
set -u
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/ex ex "${CUSTOM_NVIM_PATH}" 110
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/vi vi "${CUSTOM_NVIM_PATH}" 110
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/view view "${CUSTOM_NVIM_PATH}" 110
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/vim vim "${CUSTOM_NVIM_PATH}" 110
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/vimdiff vimdiff "${CUSTOM_NVIM_PATH}" 110
```

`Update:`

3. (Optional) If you are following ThePrimeagen video and have already you configured some stuff, you'll have to:

   1. delete the folder `plugin` in the the `.config` since it'll have auto generated data. (only the one in the parent dir) ie:

      ```bash
      rm -r ~/.config/nvim/plugin
      ```
   2. move the `after` folder somewhere else ie: `mv ~/.config/nvim/after ~/Documents` ie:

      ```bash
      mv ~/.config/nvim/plugin ~/Documents
      ```
   3. To redownload and setup the Plugins enter nvim, open `packer.lua` and run:

      ```
      :so
      :PackerSync
      ```
   4. Exit nvim, and move the `after` folder back to the `.config` folder:

      ```bash
      mv ~/Documents/after ~/.config/nvim
      ```
   5. Open nvim and it should be working normally

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a syntax problem is not the root cause of the issue here. The line `vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>pv", vim.cmd.Ex)` is functioning correctly, as it's referencing the function rather than invoking it.

In a similar situation, I encountered the same problem, but my specific issue was that I was using `vim` instead of `nvim`. This occurred when I was editing my `zsh` configuration files, and my `alias vim=nvim` was not being invoked as expected.